# Change value of one DropDownList depend on another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to set the value of a drop down list based on another drop down list :

```
<select id="workField :">
    <option value="HI-TEC">HI-TEC</option>
    <option value="Food Industry">Food Industry</option>
    <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
    <option value="Resturents">Resturents</option>
    <option value="Financial">Financial</option>        
</select>
<select id="occupetion">
    <option value="QA">QA</option>
    <option value="Food Industry">Food inspectur</option>
    <option value="Marketing">Selles man</option>
    <option value="Resturents">Bartender</option>
    <option value="Financial">Broker</option>
</select>
```

what are my options ?
i have tried this :
http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VSuBD/
still doesnt work.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you want ? Also your fiddle is working

Comment: looking for a better solution or what?? be clear

Comment: fiddle is different from what you have here!

Comment: i want to set the value of occupetion based on the user selection on field .

Comment: The code is a part of a jqurey page , and a part of a form i wish to use .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$( "#workField" ).change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "HI-TEC"){
        $("#occupetion").val("QA");
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "Food Industry"){
        $("#occupetion").val("Food Industry");
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "Marketing"){
        $("#occupetion").val("Marketing");
    }
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kgd75qhx/)**

**Update:**

According to your comments, it seems you have some problem that how to use this code, so i include a full html page code hope to be helpful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <div>
            <select id="workField">
                <option value="HI-TEC">HI-TEC</option>
                <option value="Food Industry">Food Industry</option>
                <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
            </select>
            <select id="occupetion">
                <option value="QA">QA</option>
                <option value="Food Industry">Food inspectur</option>
                <option value="Marketing">Selles man</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#workField").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "HI-TEC") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("QA");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Food Industry") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("Food Industry");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Marketing") {
                    $("#occupetion").val("Marketing");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i new at web programming , thats a js code ? and how do i use it?

Comment: I would think that this solution is not generic enough eventhough it may do what OP wants

Comment: Yes, it's a JS code, it's not fully optimized and just as a sample to put you in right way. please check Demo, if you still don't figure out how to use it, tell me to update answer.

Comment: I used the js code , tried on an extarenel file and in the page head , still doesn't work  , is there a chance that the problem is the jqurey?

Comment: Yes, you should include JQuery library to your code.
I see the JQuery tag on your question and think it's not necessary to mention that.

Comment: The coding sample though crude in implementation does not have syntax errors as far as I can see. Itsik my suggestion would be to read up on javascript/jquery/html a little bit more so you can understand what is happening here before try using it...

Comment: sorry but still doesn't work , can i send u the file or upload it here ? im starting to lose hope ... i will try your suggestion thank u !

Comment: well , thats all the code , can u tell me what im doing wrong?    https://mauyhasworkspace-c9-mauyhas.c9.io/jobCricle.html

Comment: Itsik you will never understand how to do anything useful with javascript unless you first understand the basics of a web page and how its rendered. I would suggest https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Getting_Started Also Moshtaf code is not very good as far as best practices and actually being a "useful" solution. I would not use it in your code. 1. Follows bad practices 2. Not generic 3. Not formatted well

Comment: @Moshtaf i cant write in a private room (min 20 rep) can i send u the all code by mail?

Comment: Itsik to fix your issue change the ids on the select elements to match "workField" and "occupetion" specifically. Right now you have workField as workField : or something weird

Comment: Check you mail please , @Scott Mitchell , i can send u the file , i didn't understand that last comment